# jQuery Promise async await in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, promise, async-await

I have a object with loads of functions inside. some of them are ajax calls. the idea is to call one of this functions from another place and wait until it's resolved but i don't know if it is possible and if it is im not sure how to do it. here is the code so you get an idea of what i'm trying to do.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".button").click(function(){
       let some_id = $(this).val();
       let ajax_test = binder.firstLayer['ajaxcall'](some_id);
       console.log(ajax_test);
   });
});
```

Then i have an object with all the functions i use, among them this ajax call looking something like this:

```
let binder = {
    firstLayer : {
        ajaxcall: function(some_id){
            return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                $.ajax({
                    // all the details
                }).then((response) => {
                    resolve(response);
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't included the keywords async and await because im not sure where to put them. in the case of the ajaxcall function, i tried putting the `async` after the `ajaxcall:` and before `function(some_id)` but when i put `await` like:

```
let ajax_test = await binder.firstLayer['ajaxcall'](some_id);
```

but it doesn't work. so again, the question is if it can be done the way im trying to do it and if so, what im doing wrong or putting in the wrong place. with this attempt i get `undefined` if i try to look into the response or `[object Promise]` (from `console.log(ajax_test);`) if i just console log the `response` (from same place as before)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `let ajax_test = await binder.firstLayer['ajaxcall'](some_id);` as long as you mark the function as async:

`$(".button").click(async function(){ ...`

Comment: Thanks dude! that works!! never imagined it was gonna be that simple! :P the only thing is that the place where you placed the ```async``` is going to affect the other functions? or if they don't have the ```await``` should cause any troubles? thanks again!!!

Comment: Won't affect other functions. You can only use `await` inside an `async` function, or alternatively you can use the promise `.then()` function instead.